# Причастия и отглагольные прилагательные

Tags: орфография

1. Машина была некрашеНая. (прилагательное, нет зависимых слов, НЕ слитно, одно Н в суффиксе)
2. Машина, давно не крашеННая. (причастный оборот, появилось зависимое слово "давно")
3. Машина была давно не крашеННая (причастие с зависимым словом).

   А если:

   Машина давно была некрашеная. (прилагательное?)

Когда между "причастием"(?) и зависимым словом стоит сказуемое, оно всегда остается отглагольным прилагательным?

Answer (score 1):

3) Машина давно была не крашенная. Здесь влияет наречие давно, что придает временное значение. Поэтому причастие.

Answer (score 0):

Так как машины вряд ли кто регулярно красит, лучше поговорим о домах.

1) Дом был некрашеный.

2) Давно не крашенный, серый, дом тем не менее носил следы хорошей хозяйской руки.

3) Дом был  давно не крашенный, скучный.

А вот выражение "дом давно был некрашеный" некорректно, с неясной семантикой, наречие "давно" уже не связано со словом "некрашеный", а относится к связке.

Получается что-то вроде:
Когда-то давно дом был некрашеный, а теперь его покрасили.

Вообще говоря, изучать грамматику не следует на искусственных, ПРИДУМАННЫХ  примерах, так как вы можете ошибиться в их грамматике, и тогда от такой работы не будет никакой пользы.